# compute arbitrary precision on large matrices

Tags: performance, arbitrary-precision

Sympy's `applyfunc` gets really slow on matrices, though it does compute to arbitrary precision. Is there any alternative to compute the same function on many values both fast and to arbitrary precision?

I was using numpy first before I encountered that I need arbitrary precision, which numpy does not support. But it is really fast with vectorized functions.

Any language and tool appreciated.

Comment: Arbitrary precision is what makes things slow. You can use a large fixed precision to possibly get better performance but this will be significantly slower than Numpy. For large numbers, the GMP library is pretty efficient (require a native code like C/C++ for good performance).